# A method does not override a method in its superclass

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to set the title for my action bar, but it’s given me the error message *"method does not override method in its superclass"*. I'm extending fragment.

Here's the portion I’m having problems with:

```
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

Here is the code for the whole class (it’s incomplete, because i'm still working on it):

```
package com.android.styles.radius360;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.Menu;


/**
 * Created by user on 3/23/2017.
 */

public class HomePageFragment extends Fragment {

    private String[] mOptions;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page, container, false);

        mOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mOptions));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getActivity().getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
        if(position == 0)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            SettingsPageActivity settings = new SettingsPageActivity();
            Fragment fragment = settings.createFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }
        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Fragment` doesn't have that method, so you're not overriding anything. Just remove the `@Override` annotation right above it.

Comment: Where are you calling the `setTitle()`? I can't find it in your code. `getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);` this is on `ActionBar`, not `Fragment`.

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem The `@Override` annotation is enough to cause an error.

Comment: @shmosel Missed the part about the error, my bad!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The class `Fragment` or any of its super classes seem not to have the method `public void setTitle(CharSequence title)` so you can't use the `@Override` annotation. You can remove that annotation and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

[User michaeak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056341/method-does-not-override-method-in-its-superclass/43056518#43056518) is correct, but I am just adding: Check the spelling of your override method. In the case below, I was getting the same error, because 'OnPause()' should be 'onPause' with a lower 'o':

```
@Override
protected void OnPause() { // OnPause should be onPause. It gets rid of the error
    super.onPause();
    mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error but had a different issue; I was importing `java.beans.EventHandler` when I only needed `javafx.event.EventHandler` or simply `javafx.event.*`.

Removing `java.beans.EventHandler` fixed the issue.